# Chrome-Extension/JavaScript How to make all links on page have no effect?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I just want to prevent to open a new page when click a link(it may be a img or button). And here is the code in my "content-scripts.js":

```
document.onclick = function() {
    return false;
}
```

It can work but sometimes it doesn't work and I don't know why. When I click some elements on the web page, it will still open another url.

Comment: Are you wanting to prevent **all** actions initiated by a click on the page, or only clicks which are on links (`<a>` elements) which will result in *normal page navigation* (i.e. the `<a>` has an `href`). Are you wanting to prevent JavaScript from navigating the page (i.e. not just navigation caused by the default action of an `<a href="some other page">` element)?

Comment: I don't know much about JavaScript. Actually I just want to prevent open a new webpage initiated by clicks(no matter trigger  <a> or scripts) , and I don't care what will happen on this page. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't always work because a click may not make it all the way to `document`, its bubbling may be cancelled before it gets there.

To do what you're doing, you'd have to hook `click` on **every** element on the page, and list for DOM modifications so that you can hook `click` on new elements if they're added to the page.

To process all elements, you can either walk the DOM tree recursively or get one potentially-massive list via `document.querySelectorAll("*")`.

To listen for DOM modifications so you can hook new elements as they're added, you'd want a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Because other JavaScript code may overwrite your `onclick`, I'd use `addEventListener` instead, and both stop propagation and stop immediate propagation:

```
function stopEvent(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}
someElement.addEventListener("click", stopEvent);
```

So for instance, roughly:

```
function stopEvent(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}
document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", stopEvent);
});
```

...and then use a mutation observer to handle newly-added elements.